# Why does CSRF token in session object NOT match token in meta tags or form hidden fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm debugging my devise setup, and I came across something I can't understand. In my view I have this code to output the CSRF token from the session object in development mode:

```
  - if Rails.env.development?
    %p DEVELOPMENT MODE
    = "CSRF Token: " + session[:_csrf_token].inspect
```

The output of this is definitely a CSRF token, but it doesn't match the tokens that are in the  meta tag, nor the hidden fields in the forms on the page. I have both sign up, and log in forms on one page, and they have the same token, and it matches the token in the meta tags.

Only session[:_csrf_token] is totally unique. Is there a reason for this? Where is it coming from?